# Fill table in javascript with data from db

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have an html `<table>` that I need to fill with data from a database query. The query returns 10 rows and then sends the data to the method `fill(data)` to fill the table:

```
function getTopQ() {
    alert("Get top Qs");
    callServer('fill', 'checkConnection', false, 'SelectTopQues.php');
}

function fill(data) {
    alert("ready to fill now");
    $('#table').html('');

    var search = '#table';
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $('#table').listview("refresh");
        var Questions = data[i];

        var str = '<td " ID="' + Questions[0] + 
            '"  Question="' + Questions[1] + 
            '"     UserID="' + Questions[2] + 
            '"CategoryId"' + '" SubCategoryId"' + '" DatePosted"' + '"';

        str += '">'; //end li

        str += '<a href="" data-transition="fade">';


        str += Questions[1];

        str += '</a>';

        //str += '<span class="hiddenData">' + item[13] + '</span>';
        str += '</td>';

        $('#table').append(str);

        $('#table').listview("refresh");
    }
    console.log(data);
    console.log($('#table'));
    $('#table').listview("refresh");
}
```

Comment: What is your exact problem?

Comment: i cant fill the retrieved data from the server in the table

Comment: is your problem in the database query? can you add the query, can you show the actual data that you are passing to your 'fill' method, what is the fill method supposed to do, and what is it actually doing?

Comment: Where you call `fill` function?

Comment: What does your `callServer('fill','checkConnection',false,'SelectTopQues.php');` ?